# query with nullable parameter in hive table

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

The table contains a field, say A. It can be null or a string. Now I use a parameter to query rows where A == parameter. Default value of the parameter can be null or empty string. How to get the rows that have the following logic:
if A is null and parameter is null, the row is selected,
if parameter is not null and A= parameter, the row is selected.

sth like
select * where A = {parameter}

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
where a = <parameter> or (a is null and <parameter> is null)
```